# Size of a C struct

Tags: objective-c, struct, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

I have a simple C struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct LMWinData {
    UInt8   itemTypeID;
    UInt16  serviceID;
    UInt16  methodID;
} LMWinData;
```

Later in code I define a variable of this type like this one:

```
LMWinData   lmWinData;
```

Now, if I print out the size of this variable:

```
NSLog(@"data has size of %lu bytes", sizeof(lmWinData));
```

I don't get the value (5 bytes) as expected. I get a size of 6 bytes instead.

So, what's wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

(I'm using Mac OS X Lion.)

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing an alignment issue here.   This can be a tricky problem when dealing with compilers that are attempting to make software access locations efficiently.   In particular, you have a structure wherein two 16-bit integers follow an 8-bit, causing the 16-bit integers to start at an odd location, which is generally slow.

However, there are cases when this is necessary, and the clang/llvm method for controlling alignment and padding is `__attribute__((packed))`.

or, to use on your structure:

```
typedef struct LMWinData {
    UInt8   itemTypeID;
    UInt16  serviceID;
    UInt16  methodID;
} __attribute__((packed)) LMWinData;
```

I think this also works in modern gcc, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at structure padding, alignment. There are ways to force alignment in certain compilers:

```
typedef struct LMWinData {
    UInt8   itemTypeID;
    UInt16  serviceID;
    UInt16  methodID;
} LMWinData __attribute__ ((aligned (1)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the 'pragma pack(1)' method and that fixed the problem.